# Loading Views into ContentControl and changing their properties by clicking buttons

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, expression-blend, contentcontrol

I have a mvvm(model view viewmodel) silverlight application that has several views that need to be loaded into ContentControls (i made it all in expression blend). What i dont know how to do is, for example, to load one view (user control) in one content control by clicking a button from another view that is in another content control. To make it easier to understand the problem, i need to do something similar to this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/BlendableVMCom.aspx

with that difference that child1 and child2 are supposed to be loaded into theirown content controls by clicking Call child1 or call child2 buttons.

and example would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out Caliburn Micro, screens and conductors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is very simplified, but I think you now how to adjust it to your application.

The main view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="commandsView">
        <Button Content="Call view 1" Command="{Binding CallView1Command}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" />
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="displayedView" Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I haven't created separated views as user controls, here are just borders, which can be replaced by real views.

Different view models for different views in code behind:

```
this.commandsView.DataContext = new CommandsViewModel();
this.displayedView.DataContext = new DisplayedViewModel();
```

First view model conains the command which sends the message to another view model:

```
public class CommandsViewModel
{
    public CommandsViewModel()
    {
        this.CallView1Command = new RelayCommand(() => 
          Messenger.Default.Send<View1Message>(new View1Message()));
    }

    public RelayCommand CallView1Command { get; set; }

}

public class View1Message : MessageBase
{

}
```

To make this example work, download the [MVVM Light library](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/&rct=j&q=mvvm%20light&ei=vrXJTfzzE8WeOoX60d4H&usg=AFQjCNEcVCaGK8-SwUfSe-yMEQbR2XBwDw&cad=rja).

The second view model receive the message and creates a view for its property:

```
public class DisplayedViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DisplayedViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<View1Message>(this, obj => 
            this.CurrentView = new TextBlock { Text = "Pressed the button 1 and now here is the view 1" });
    }

    private object currentView;

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return currentView; }
        set
        {
            currentView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }
}
```

Again, it is possible to use clr object instead of controls and apply data templates in xaml, but there will not be enough space to provide all the resulting code.

So that is all, the main idea is a some kind of event aggregator, which is the `Messenger` class in this particular case.

Without the MVVM Light it will require more code:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var events = new GlobalEvents();
        this.commandsView.DataContext = new CommandsViewModel(events);
        this.displayedView.DataContext = new DisplayedViewModel(events);
    }
}

public class GlobalEvents
{
    public event EventHandler View1Event = delegate { };

    public void RaiseView1Event()
    {
        View1Event(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Commands which call different views
/// </summary>
public class CommandsViewModel
{
    public CommandsViewModel(GlobalEvents globalEvents)
    {
        this.CallView1Command = new DelegateCommand(globalEvents.RaiseView1Event);
    }

    public DelegateCommand CallView1Command { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Model where views are changed and then displayed
/// </summary>
public class DisplayedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DisplayedViewModel(GlobalEvents globalEvents)
    {
        globalEvents.View1Event += (s,e) =>
            this.CurrentView = new TextBlock { Text = "Pressed the button 1 and now here is the view 1" };
    }

    private object currentView;

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return currentView; }
        set
        {
            currentView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

In this example you must change the `DelegateCommand` class for something different. Other code will work for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the example vorrtex but I must do this without using any mvvm toolkits, which means i must code all mvvm on my own. I also find your example confusing a bit.. I dont know what is "Messenger.Default.Register<View1Message>"

Comment: @deckard cain The `Messenger` is the class in the MVVM Light toolkit. Anyway I have added the code how to implement the same functionality without custom frameworks.

Comment: @vortex thanks again but, i cant seem to figure where are you loading the views into the content

Comment: @deckard cain There is the line `ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"` in the xaml. And there is the property `CurrentView` in the view model. If you change this property - the changes will be reflected in the user interface. In my example I set the TextBlock to this property, but you can set any UserControl.

Comment: @vorrtex Thanks for the reply. I'll see if i can implement that on my project. If you want you can take a look at this 
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=G2I0KVR2
That's my small mvvm project that im trying to do. LoadUnloadControl loads into its content when the application starts, and i need to load other control into the lower content control by clicking load and unload it by clicking unload. But i didnt know how to implement that..

Comment: @deckard cain No problems: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/MVVMRawTest%20Fixed.zip. Just added few lines of code with few changes in the structure of the views and models. Also I would use the `DataTemplateSelector` class, because it is better to use clr-object inside view models rather than controls, but I haven't changed this.

Comment: @vorrtex Thanks a lot for your help, you are a genius :). If i have any more questions, i'll feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to do some sort of navigation. If that's true, check out the [Silverlight navigation framework.](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx)